# Trying to use an NPM package but keeps can't find 'fs'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs2, fs

In my vue project. I am attempting to use an npm package called `https://www.npmjs.com/package/baidu-translate-api`. I have run it on the RunKit and its working fine. But as soon as I try to use it in my vue project, it fails to compile. I get the following 3 errors.

`ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js`
`ERROR in ./node_modules/make-dir/index.js`
`ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js`

Comment: Because baidu-translate-api is server package and you're trying to use it on client side which doesn't have `fs` and cannot make the listed packages work - primarily `request`.

Comment: I think that makes sense. Currently I am uses `npm run dev` to start the development page. Is there a way I can make this not client sided?

Comment: You need to set up Node web server, use baidu-translate-api in REST API and do requests to it from client side, that's how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: I don’t think that is the issue. I made a simple http request and it was successful. So I’m able to contact information from the internet. It’s only this one where it says it can’t find fs...

Comment: The ability of inability to do requests is not an issue here. You physically can't access `fs` from client-side application - because there's no such thing there, besides many other things that baidu-translate-api uses. baidu-translate-api is *server-side* Node package. It will never work as a part of *client-side* application. It should run in *server-side* application. A way to interact between *client-side* Vue application and *server-side* Node application is to run web server inside Node application and make requests to it from client side.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don’t quite follow. I can use google apis and apis requests from the internet but this Baidu translate doesn’t seem to work. Are there any useful resources you can point me to if you still think it’s the same problem?

Comment: Additionally I am running the application from a browser using “npm run dev” does this also constitute server aided?

Comment: You can use Google APIs because they are free and intended to be consumed from client side. I can't say if Baidu API can be used in similar way as I don't use it. API endpoints that this package uses could be unaccessible for client-side usage, https://github.com/TimLuo465/baidu-translate-api/blob/master/src/translate.js#L13 . You can check on your own if you can use them and do AJAX requests to these URLs. If you can, the package may be unneeded. As for this specific NPM package, it's for Node, end of the story.

Comment: Yes, `npm run dev` runs Node web server. It serves static files. It isn't supposed to be modified for personal needs. In case you need to provide HTTP API for your app, run another web server. It's very common setup that Vue/React/Angular app is powered with one web server (e.g. localhost:3000 locally and www.example.com remotely) and API is powered with another (localhost:4000 locally and api.example.com remotely). I cannot recommend any specific reading, this is a common knowledge about app architecture.